# How would I register a piece of script, just once, given numerous subsequent asynchronous postbacks? Please read on

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, scriptmanager

I have been left sratching my head!  I have used the appropriate overload as suggested by MSDN to only render a script at least once over many async postback...and here is what I have....What is going on!!

```
  if (!ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).GetRegisteredClientScriptBlocks().Any(x=> x.Key ==   jscriptKey))
        {
          //  Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock(jscriptKey, "");
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), jscriptKey, sb.ToString(), true);
        }
```

Comment: The registerad scripts are not ViewState persisted. Also you should use Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(typeof(Page), "Key") instead of linq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client script block registrations do not persist in ScriptManager through any hidden mechanism. That is, if you look at `GetRegisteredClientScriptBlocks()` it is *always* going to be empty after a postback (async or otherwise). However, though ClientScriptManager may be unaware that a script has already been added to the non-asynchronously-updated part of the page, anything that was added there will, of course, still be there after an async postback. You need to keep track of your registrations in your code somehow  -- and use logic to only register them once.

What's your situation? Do you have a usercontrol or something that needs to register script? You could either check `Page.IsPostBack`, and only register if it's not a postback, or if that's not good enough (because the control could be loaded for the first time on a postback) then set a flag in ViewState so it knows when it's already registered its script.

Comment: It was quite a convoluted problem.  I had originally used a Session Variable, without thinking to use Viewstate, as the control is used in different contexts Viewstate makes good sense (managing this with session is more onerous!) 
However, the situation was complicated by using a ModalPopupExtendeer and ensuring that specifc logic would run after either a postback or async postback. I wanted to run the logic "just once" as not to accumulate DOM changes effected by the script, which would be the case if it did run more than once! 1 1/2 days on this problem. Very expensive indeed....

Comment: To add further, the modalpopupextender (mpe) exposes a simple API to add events to call back on various events.  These don't always work. For example. I have had to explicitly raise a shown event (mpe.raiseShown()) when performing a partial postback because the registered callback handler isnt invoked correctly...

Comment: Ah... ajax control toolkit in the house :) There is a lot about that that doesn't always work... start using jquery now. You will thank me later :)